# Problem getting DQN to learn CartPole-v1 (PyTorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

So I had my DQN training fine, solves the environment after ~65_000 iterations. However, I started working on something else and now it's completely broken and won't get to even close to the same level anymore.

Following advice from previous work, I tuned hyperparameters and still didn't see the same results anymore.

```py
import gym
import numpy as np

import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torch import optim

from models import DQN
from memory import Memory
from utils import wrap_input, epsilon_greedy

def main() -> int:
    env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    # Online and offline model for learning
    model = DQN(env.observation_space, env.action_space, 24).to(device)
    target = DQN(env.observation_space, env.action_space, 24).to(device)
    target.eval()

    # Optimizer and loss function
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=.001)
    loss_fn = F.smooth_l1_loss


    memory = Memory(10_000)
    obs, info = env.reset()

    for it in range(65_000):
        # Do this for the batch norm
        model.eval()

        # Maybe explore
        if np.random.random() <= epsilon_greedy(1.0, .01, 15_000, it):
            state = wrap_input(obs, device).unsqueeze(0)
            action  = model(state).argmax().item()
        else:
            action = env.action_space.sample()

        # Act in environment and store the memory
        next_state, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        if truncated or done:
            next_state = np.zeros(env.observation_space.shape)
        memory.store([obs, action, reward, int(done), next_state])
        done = done or truncated

        if done:
            obs, info = env.reset()

        # Train
        if len(memory) > 32:
            model.train()
            states, actions, rewards, dones, next_states = memory.sample(32)

            # Wrap and move all values to the cpu
            states = wrap_input(states, device)
            actions = wrap_input(actions, device, torch.int64, reshape=True)
            next_states = wrap_input(next_states, device)
            rewards = wrap_input(rewards, device, reshape=True)
            dones = wrap_input(dones, device, reshape=True)

            # Get current q-values
            qs = model(states)
            qs = torch.gather(qs, dim=1, index=actions)

            # Compute target q-values
            with torch.no_grad():
                next_qs, _ = target(next_states).max(dim=1)
                next_qs = next_qs.reshape(-1, 1)

            target_qs = rewards + .9 * (1 - dones) * next_qs.reshape(-1, 1)

            # Compute loss
            loss = loss_fn(qs, target_qs)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            
            # Clip gradients
            nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1)

            # Backprop
            optimizer.step()

            # soft update
            with torch.no_grad():
                for target_param, local_param in zip(target.parameters(), model.parameters()):
                    target_param.data.copy_(1e-2 * local_param.data + (1 - 1e-2) * target_param.data)


        if it % 200 == 0:
            target.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())

# models.py
class FlatExtractor(nn.Module):
    '''Does nothing but pass the input on'''
    def __init__(self, obs_space):
        super(FlatExtractor, self).__init__()

        self.n_flatten = obs_space.shape[0]

    def forward(self, obs):
        return obs


class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, obs_space, act_space, layer_size):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()

        # Feature extractor
        if len(obs_space.shape) == 1:
            self.feature_extractor = FlatExtractor(obs_space)
        elif len(obs_space.shape) == 3:
            self.feature_extractor = NatureCnn(obs_space)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedErorr("This type of environment is not supported")

        # Neural network
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.feature_extractor.n_flatten, layer_size),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(layer_size),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(layer_size, layer_size),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(layer_size),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(layer_size, act_space.n),
        )

    def forward(self, obs):
        return self.net(self.feature_extractor(obs))

# memory.py
import random
from collections import deque

class Memory(object):
    def __init__(self, maxlen):
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=maxlen)

    def store(self, experience):
        self.memory.append(experience)

    def sample(self, n_samples):
        return zip(*random.sample(self.memory, n_samples))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory)

# utils.py
def wrap_input(arr, device, dtype=torch.float, reshape=False):
    output = torch.from_numpy(np.array(arr)).type(dtype).to(device)
    if reshape:
        output = output.reshape(-1, 1)

    return output

def epsilon_greedy(start, end, n_steps, it):
    return max(start - (start - end) * (it / n_steps), end)
```

Is there something that I'm greatly missing? I've tried training for longer it doesn't change. What seems to be the biggest problem is that the loss explodes, and even changing the tau for hard updates didn't seem to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a lot of difficulty getting your code to run, therefore I had to comment several things out. I also commented things that added unnecessary complexity while debugging, for instance, a simple environment like cartpole doesn't require a target network. Also, focus more on the total reward gained, instead of the loss.

A few major changes that I made were -

0. At the end of the iteration, the next_state should become the current_state -

```
obs = next_state
```

1. I swapped your explore and exploit code

```
        if np.random.random() <= epsilon_greedy(1.0, .01, 15_000, it):
            state = wrap_input(obs, device).unsqueeze(0)
            action  = model(state).argmax().item()
        else:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
```

Your code basically starts off exploiting by taking the argmax and once the epsilon value is low enough, it starts randomly sampling. This needs to be swapped.

I replaced it with -

```
        if np.random.random() <= epsilon_greedy(1.0, .01, 15_000, it):
            action = env.action_space.sample()
            

            

        else:
            state = wrap_input(obs, device).unsqueeze(0)
            action  = model(state).argmax().item()
```

2. I increased your batch size. A larger batch size in cartpole, speeds up training considerably -

```
states, actions, rewards, dones, next_states = memory.sample(128)
```

3. Also, it is a good idea to wait for your model to gain sufficient experiences before starting training -

```
        if len(memory) > 500:
            model.train()
            states, actions, rewards, dones, next_states = memory.sample(128)
```

The other changes that I made were to ease up debugging.

4. I didn't see any use of `class FlatExtractor(nn.Module)`, therefore I removed it and made the following change -

```
        if len(obs_space.shape) == 1:
            self.feature_extractor = env.observation_space.shape[0]
```

```
    def forward(self, obs):

        return self.net(obs)
```

5. I removed all instances of BatchNorm
6. Replaced loss with MSELoss and removed clip gradients

```
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
```

7. Changed the learning rate to `lr=.0001`
8. Increased the width of your neural network -

```
model = DQN(env.observation_space, env.action_space, 128).to(device)
```

9. Removed the target network and its corresponding soft updates.
10. Added in total reward to check if the algorithm is learning

```
    tot_rew = 0
    for it in range(65_000):
```

```
        next_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        tot_rew += reward
```

```
        if done:
            print("tot_rew = ", tot_rew)
            obs= env.reset()
            tot_rew = 0
```

Here is the total reward I get at the end -

```
tot_rew =  228.0
tot_rew =  472.0
tot_rew =  243.0
tot_rew =  300.0
```

Here is the entire fixed code -

```
import gym
import numpy as np

import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torch import optim

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
def main() -> int:
    
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    # Online and offline model for learning

    model = DQN(env.observation_space, env.action_space, 128).to(device)

    target = DQN(env.observation_space, env.action_space, 24).to(device)

    # target.eval()

    # Optimizer and loss function
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=.0001)
    loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()


    memory = Memory(10_000)

    obs = env.reset()
    tot_rew = 0
    for it in range(65_000):
        # print("it = ", it)
        # Do this for the batch norm
        # model.eval()

        # Maybe explore
        if np.random.random() <= epsilon_greedy(1.0, .01, 15_000, it):
            action = env.action_space.sample()
            

            

        else:
            state = wrap_input(obs, device).unsqueeze(0)
            action  = model(state).argmax().item()
            


            # print("epsilon_greedy(1.0, .01, 15_000, it) = ", epsilon_greedy(1.0, .01, 15_000, it))
            
            # print("check = ", model(state).detach().numpy())
            # print("action = ", action)
            


        # Act in environment and store the memory

        next_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        tot_rew += reward
        if done:
            next_state = np.zeros(env.observation_space.shape)
        memory.store([obs, action, reward, int(done), next_state])
        done = done

        obs = next_state

        if done:
            print("tot_rew = ", tot_rew)
            obs= env.reset()
            tot_rew = 0

        # Train
        if len(memory) > 500:
            model.train()
            states, actions, rewards, dones, next_states = memory.sample(128)

            # Wrap and move all values to the cpu

            states = wrap_input(states, device)
            # print("states.shape = ",states.shape)
            actions = wrap_input(actions, device, torch.int64, reshape=True)
            next_states = wrap_input(next_states, device)
            rewards = wrap_input(rewards, device, reshape=True)
            dones = wrap_input(dones, device, reshape=True)

            # Get current q-values
            qs = model(states)
            # print("qs.shape = ", qs.shape)
            qs = torch.gather(qs, dim=1, index=actions)

            # Compute target q-values
            with torch.no_grad():
                next_qs, _ = model(next_states).max(dim=1)
                next_qs = next_qs.reshape(-1, 1)

            target_qs = rewards + .9 * (1 - dones) * next_qs.reshape(-1, 1)

            # Compute loss
            loss = loss_fn(qs, target_qs)
            # print("loss.shape = ", loss)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            
            # Clip gradients
            # nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1)

            # Backprop
            optimizer.step()

            # soft update
        #     with torch.no_grad():
        #         for target_param, local_param in zip(target.parameters(), model.parameters()):
        #             target_param.data.copy_(1e-2 * local_param.data + (1 - 1e-2) * target_param.data)


        # if it % 200 == 0:
        #     target.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())

# models.py
class FlatExtractor(nn.Module):
    '''Does nothing but pass the input on'''
    def __init__(self, obs_space):
        super(FlatExtractor, self).__init__()

        self.n_flatten = 1

    def forward(self, obs):
        return obs


class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, obs_space, act_space, layer_size):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()

        # Feature extractor
        if len(obs_space.shape) == 1:
            self.feature_extractor = env.observation_space.shape[0]

        elif len(obs_space.shape) == 3:
            self.feature_extractor = NatureCnn(obs_space)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedErorr("This type of environment is not supported")
        

        # Neural network
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.feature_extractor, layer_size),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(layer_size, layer_size),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(layer_size, act_space.n),
        )

    def forward(self, obs):

        return self.net(obs)

# memory.py
import random
from collections import deque

class Memory(object):
    def __init__(self, maxlen):
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=maxlen)

    def store(self, experience):
        self.memory.append(experience)

    def sample(self, n_samples):
        return zip(*random.sample(self.memory, n_samples))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory)

# utils.py
def wrap_input(arr, device, dtype=torch.float, reshape=False):
    output = torch.from_numpy(np.array(arr)).type(dtype).to(device)
    if reshape:
        output = output.reshape(-1, 1)

    return output

def epsilon_greedy(start, end, n_steps, it):
    return max(start - (start - end) * (it / n_steps), end)

main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the throughout debugging, posting the full fixed code could also be very useful for future visitors to have a working start for this project!

Comment: Great find on the action sampling, definitely missed that one! For the MSELoss, I followed StableBaselines3 use of Smoothl1Loss, but I've used MSELoss previously. The feature extractor is a bit overcomplicated, but it's there so that when I transition to image-based environments, the DQN can just swap to that for it's feature extractor. Interesting with the batchnorm, I'll try with and without to make sure it's the same results for both. Overall, thanks!

Comment: ... I think the thing that I forgot the most was obs = next_state. Big oops

Comment: Oh dang, I forgot to include that in the debugging information. Although it is there in the full code.